# Rails wildcard routes : vs *

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wildcard, routes

I'm starting to learn rails, and I'm seeing the terminology wildcard routes, but I've seen routes listed both of the following ways:

```
/a/path/*all', :all => /.*/
```

and

```
/a/path/:all
```

What is the difference between these two route forms?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you read **[the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)** on routing yet? That is a great place to start learning about routing in Rails.

For instance, you will learn that your 2nd code block is **not** a wildcard route. Instead it matches what the guide above refers to as a **[Static Segment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments)**

You'll also learn that to impose restrictions on a segment as you appear to be attempting in the first code block, you must use the `:constraints` option, such as this **wildcard route**, or as the guide above refers to them, **[Route Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments)**

```
GET  "/a/path/*all", :constraints => { :all => /.*/ }
```

However, the above constraint is redundant since the wildcard `*all` is going to match `.*` by default anyway.